# Reasoning behind formula for eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In 3blue1browns excellent linear algebra series, he [indicates](https://youtu.be/PFDu9oVAE-g?t=7m17s) there are $2$ solutions for the formula 
$$
(A - \lambda I)\vec{v} = \vec{0}
$$

One is obviously if $\vec{v}$ is a zero vector, but the other is if the matrix transformation reduces the dimension, "squishing" the eigenvector to zero. i.e. $$\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$$

This makes *some* intuitive sense to me, but algebraically I don't understand why you can't just set the other part of the equation to 0 and solve for it, i.e.

$$A - \lambda I = 0$$

$$A = \lambda I$$

Is there a reason this isn't a valid solution?

Comment: Because $A$ is fixed, and $A v = 0$ does not imply that $A = 0$ or $v = 0$.

Comment: Its not a matrix equation. Its a polynomial... Dont forget the $det(...)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are interested in finding all solution pairs for $(\lambda, v)$ such that $(A-\lambda I)v=0$ and $v \ne 0$.

If you set $A-\lambda I = 0$, it might not have a solution, it only has a solution when $A$ is a diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries being equal. In fact when $A$ is a diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries being equal, you would have solved for the $\lambda$ correctly, it is the diagonal entries and any non-zero $v$

Secondly, fortunately for $(A-\lambda I)v =0$ where $v \ne 0$, we know how to solve the problem.  It doesn't require $A-\lambda I$ to be equal to zero. Since $v \neq 0$, we know that we require $\det (A-\lambda I)=0$, which is equivalent to solving for the root of a polynomial.

Comment: I think the root of what I'm stuck on is why A = lambda * v "might not have a solution". Shouldn't the formula itself indicate that it must be a valid solution? Why can't I treat it like a polynomial, especially considering we assume the zero vector would in fact be a valid solution.

Comment: Try to work with explicit matrices, for example, consider $A = \begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$, $A - \lambda I = \begin{bmatrix}  1-\lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 2-\lambda \end{bmatrix}$, and you can see you that $A- \lambda I$ has no solution.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that the matrix has properties that prevent it from being solved like a polynomial, but applying the determinant distills it down to components that can?

Comment: For matrices, $AB=0$ does not imply $A=0$ or $B=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvectors of a matrix are vectors that get scaled with multiplication.  So $A v = \lambda v$ for some value of $\lambda$.  If we subtract $\lambda v$ from both sides, we get $A v - \lambda v = (A - \lambda I) v = 0$.  To find an eigenvector, then, we're looking for a non-trivial vector in the null space of the matrix $A-\lambda I$.